# Amazon API rental info

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to get rental info from the Amazon book API?
I can't find anything in the Amazon API documentation.

This page contains all the ResponseGroups: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ResponseGroupsList.html

Comment: If you can't find it in the API documentation, it probably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioned a few times on Amazon web services forums that this is currently not available

> **Rental Book Prices?**
>
> Is there a way to get rental book pricing from the API yet? I'm unable
>   to find any documentation on this. For example:
>   [http://www.amazon.com/Accounting-Information-Systems-Marshall-Romney/dp/0132552620](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132552620)
>
> Also, what about buyback pricing? This would be helpful too.
>
> > None of this is possible in PA-API (and unlikely to be in the near
> >     future with features being removed rather than added), sorry to
> >     disappoint.

via https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=378039&#378039

> **How to get book rental prices via the Product Advertising API?**
>
> Hi, I can see a number of websites (gettextbooks.com, bigwords.com)
>   showing book rental prices. However there is no mention in the API
>   docs how to retrieve the rental prices. Any idea how to fetch them?
>
> > Using the API, as mentioned, you can't. The only other way is scraping
> >     ... which I don't recommend.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=386374&#386374

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I wanted to correct this with some updated information. It is possible to retrieve "Buy back" pricing from Amazon. Those details are contained within the ItemAttributes section under "TradeInValue". Further details can be found here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_response_elements.html#TradeInValue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).